# retrieve last record of the day for the last 7 days

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to retrieve the most recent record on each day for the last 7 days. However, each record returned has an identical date for updatedAt (the most recent day), but the other data does return correctly. How can I change my sql query to give me the correct date for each record?

```
SELECT pl_scores.* FROM pl_scores
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(updatedAt) AS maxUpdatedAt FROM pl_scores
GROUP BY DATE(updatedAt)) as Lookup ON Lookup.MaxUpdatedAt = pl_scores.updatedAt
WHERE pl_scores.pid = 977 ORDER BY pl_scores.updatedAt ASC LIMIT 7
```

Comment: which columns are in your tables ? You should try something like SELECT tab1.col1, tab1.col2....tab2.colN, max(updatedAt) as max FRom tab1 join tab2 on (not sure about the bindings) ....group by max ORDER BY pl_scores.updatedAt ASC LIMIT 7.

Answer (score 2):

You have to `GROUP BY` `DAY(updatedAT)` your results in order to get the `MAX` for each day - also, add the `WHERE updatedAT >= DATE_SUB(updatedAt, INTERVAL 1 WEEK )` clause to be sure that you are not getting values older than a week.

Also, change the join and use the `id` column, in order to avoid the case where 2 records have the same `updatedAt` value

```
SELECT pl_scores.* FROM pl_scores
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT MAX(updatedAt) AS maxUpdatedAt, id FROM pl_scores 
   WHERE updatedAT >= DATE_SUB(updatedAt, INTERVAL 1 WEEK ) 
   GROUP BY DAY(updatedAt)) as Lookup ON Lookup.id = pl_scores.id
WHERE pl_scores.pid = 977 ORDER BY pl_scores.updatedAt ASC LIMIT 7
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

that kind of depends on how your db stores the time/date and why/when/how that changes. how many time/date fields have you and how stored?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT pl_scores.* FROM pl_scores
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(updatedAt) AS maxUpdatedAt, id FROM pl_scores WHERE updatedAT >= DATE_SUB(updatedAt, INTERVAL 1 WEEK ) 
GROUP BY DAY(updatedAt)) as Lookup ON Lookup.id = pl_scores.id
WHERE pl_scores.pid = 977 ORDER BY pl_scores.updatedAt ASC LIMIT 7
```